# Cannot restore CDC-enabled DB on Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, change-data-capture

While restoring database I got this error

**SQL Server cannot load database 'XXX' because Change Data Capture is enabled. The currently installed edition of SQL Server does not support Change Data Capture. Either disable Change Data Capture in the database by using a supported edition of SQL Server, or upgrade the instance to one that supports Change Data Capture.**

Mine SQL Server
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (Intel X86)   Jun 28 2012 08:42:37   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7600: ) 
I know there is no feature of CDC in Express Edition but i got XXX.bak file which i need to restore on my sql server. Is there any way of script to remove CDC feature from the file?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645938(v=sql.100).aspx) this error appears when `KEEP_CDC` is specified (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178615(v=sql.100).aspx) for `RESTORE`). How are you restoring the DB and what happens if you restore it without using that command? There is no supported way to edit a SQL Server backup other than restoring it.

Comment: I was given the backup database file ie. XXXX.bak File. and i need to restore it in mine free Express SQL server version. 
RESTORE DATABASE [dbname] FROM  DISK = N'D:\XXXX.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'XXXX_dat' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\XXXX.mdf',  MOVE N'XXXX_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\XXXX.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
This is the script but i guess i have no option. I have to use developer or evaluation version.

Comment: Using Developer Edition would be a better solution anyway: if your client (?) has Enterprise Edition then you should work with an equivalent edition to make sure that you both have exactly the same functionality available. Otherwise you can problems like this, where you use a feature that is not available to your client or vice versa.